# How does one obtain a Clan emblem in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to get a clan emblem. I think that asking players how they got theirs is the best idea.

Just to clarify, I am looking for a way to upload and customize the emblem for the clan itself, not user profile decal.

Answer (score 3):

Clans can create and upload a custom image to appear before clan members’ town hall structures in-game.

Decals must be square images with size less or equal than 256x256, both PNG or JPG are acceptable, GIF is not

1. Put your decal into this folder: `\Documents\StarCraft II\ImageUploads\
2. Head over to your Clan or Group's Info tab and hit the "Edit Info" button if you'd like to add flair to your club with a custom icon.

[image: how to install]

*Remember. Decal color may vary depending on the map lighting. 
This means that on winter maps your decal may have blue-cyan tone,
when on red maps your decal will be slighty colored with red.*

Source: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/starcraft-2/437351-custom-decals